# DataGridView: Highlight Cell and Row differently

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I highlight the row and current cell in a datagridview differently?
I have `SelectionMode` set to `CellSelect` and `MultiSelect` set to `False`.

I want the whole row to be highlighted and the selected cell to be highlighted in a different color. Basically something like this:
[image]

I'm trying to use the `CellEnter` event to do so with this code:

```
dgvResult.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightBlue;
dgvResult.SelectedCells[0].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
dgvResult.Refresh();
```

Unfortunately the first line seems to only work when `Selection Mode` is set to `FullRowSelect` and the second row only works when set to `CellSelect`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little trickier than one may hope.

You need to either keep track of the colors you set to the cells or reset all each time.
The latter is more reliable imo.

The DGV is in `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`.

Note: Resetting a `DefaultCellStyle Color` is done by setting it to `Color.Empty`.

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;

    foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
       row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
    foreach ( DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
       cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.RosyBrown;
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
}
```

Other events should also work..

**Upddate:**

As Jimi noted instead of resetting before setting in the same click event one can use the `CellLeave` event paired with the `CellEnter` event to do the same. Seems to work fine from my tests:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.RosyBrown;
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I think, if you save the a CellStyle (or the `DefaultCellStyle`) somewhere, then you can modify the Cell selection Colors on `CellEnter()` -> `If ([Cell].Selected) { SelectionBackColor = ... }` then on `CellLeave()` re-apply the `DefaultCellStyle` (not verified, but I think I've  done that sometimes and IIRC it works, so a `foreach` isn't required anymore).

Comment: @Jimi awesome! Just what I wanted. Thank you guys a lot!